# Is strong identifier the default with @property statement?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning Objective-C and the Cocoa Framework (via Aaron Hillgass' book) and trying to figure out why the following line includes the "strong" identifier.

```
@property (strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

As I understand it, strong is the default so why do I need to explicitly declare it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can declare it without writing anything, But what happens when you come back to code or some other developer looks at your code?

You might have the knowledge that the default will be set to strong, but junior level programmer will get so confused to determine whether the declared variable is strong or weak.

Comment: Another reason is for backwards compatibility. If I was to try and use that code on an older version of the iOS SDK (which is rare, but still possible), I would get a compile error, because `strong` wouldn't be recognized. However, if there was no qualifier, it would compile fine, but it would most likely end up in memory management crashes later on down the line, as before ARC, properties defaulted to __unsafe_unretained.

Comment: The default has not seemed to change.  It still seems to be `assign`, probably just for the reason @RichardJ.RossIII says.

Comment: @borrrden the default has changed, for object types. The compiler is smart enough to know that, if I have a property that is an object, it should be strong, not assign.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Then what's with the documentation language in the other answer?

Comment: @borrrden that document was last updated last year, before the release of ARC. It is now outdated, and while it contains good information, it's not all correct now.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII You are absolutely right!  I found the correct information:  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property Actually the document in the other answer was updated on the release day of iOS 5 (go figure...)

Comment: Disagree with the answer, more so with the reasoning but I guess that's because this is a few years old. I wonder what the recommended best practice is these days.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Richard.

//Strong and Weak References
 ARC introduces two new object reference qualifiers: strong and weak.

Under ARC, all object reference variables are strong by default. 
 And this doesn’t apply to just properties; 
 the default identifier with @property statement is assign for non-object types, 
 for object type should be strong.
 all object references - property values, instance variables, automatic variables,
 parameter variables, and static variables - act like a retain property under ARC.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, if you have a property with type `id` it is considered an object reference, so it will default to `strong` as well.

Answer (score -2):

In [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html):

> **assign**
>
> Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. This
>   attribute is the default.

That is, the default attribute for the setter semantics is **assign**, rather than **strong**.

Comment: Unfortunately, this document is outdated. The clang compiler docs are more recent, and contain the proper information. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property